# Adding items to ListView throws Catastrophic Failure exception

Tags: data-binding, windows-8, windows-runtime

I have this List View and a Button:

```
<ListView x:Name="MyList" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Grid.Row="1"></ListView>
<Button x:Name="Add" Content="Add Item" Click="Add_Click" Grid.Row="2" />
```

I initialize a list of strings and assign it to the ListView:

```
List<string> names;

private void FillListView()
{
    names = new List<string>();
    names.Add("Foo");
    MyList.DataContext = names;
}

private void Add_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyList.Items.Add("Bar");
}
```

There is also a handler to add one more string to the ListView, but when I click the button, I get **Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))**.

I have also try adding the new string directly into the collection, like this:

```
private void Add_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    names.Add("Bar");
}
```

In this case, ListView is not updated and when I touch it, I get **Value does not fall within the exception range 0x80070057**.

How do I bind a collection to a ListView and then add more items?

Comment: Rename the button like this "btnAdd" I suspect button name can generate confusion on compiler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your additions via your ViewModel, not on the ListView itself, so your code here is dead on:

```
private void Add_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    names.Add("Bar");
}
```

you just need to change the type of `names` from List to [ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp) so that when items are added/removed, the binding engine is notified and will reflect the changes in the UI.

```
    ObservableCollection<string> names;

    private void FillListView()
    {
        names = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        names.Add("Foo");
        MyList.DataContext = names;
    }
```

Comment: that wont work, names has to be a public property, also just assigning to the datacontext does not work, you have to use a binding

Comment: it works just fine (I don't post code unless I test it or provide a disclaimer that I haven't tried it).  Here, names is property of the Page, not the best design, but it's clear the OP is just getting used to the MVVM model, data binding, etc., so refactoring seemed out of context.  Also, it does utilize the XAML provided in the question, I just didn't repeat that in my response.

Comment: names.Add("foo") worked, any reason why MyList.Items.Add("Bar") does not work?

Comment: MyList.Items.Add works ok, but not in conjunction with also using binding, and it sort of makes sense because by mixing the two it's ambiguous as to who should win.  Think of setting up the datacontext/binding as putting a "lock" on the control so that other avenues of adapting it fail.  If you're adding items to visual controls in code you're probably doing it wrong :)

Comment: sorry, I didn't know the changed notification will work without a binding... I stand corrected :)

Comment: @pivoting, there is a binding ItemsSource is set to {Binding} in the XAML